# Run query in the background

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database which I'm working on. It is composed of split database, both front and multiple links to backend tables.

I am working on a report which is composed of 15 different sub-reports.  I have a form which allows me to input start date and end date for the report.  There's a button which generates the final report.  The problem is when I want to generate the report, I would have to re-run each of the different make-table queries for each of the sub-reports.  The issue with this is that there would be 2 warnings for each query, one to delete my table and another for rows added to the table.

I researched online and found this code to run the Execute command which will remove all the warnings.  I'm new to VB but I figured I'll give it a try and I get the following run-time error "3078: The MS Access database engine cannot find the input table or query".  I checked the query name and it matches so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  I've only tried one of the 15 queries so I can make sure it works.  Once I get this to work, my other question is would combining all these into 15 execute commands work in the module?

```
Private Sub PS_Report_Date_AfterUpdate()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim lngRowsAffected As Long
Dim lngRowsDeleted As Long
Dim sql$

sql = "[qry_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced]"

Set dbs = CurrentDb

' Execute runs both saved queries and SQL strings
dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

' Get the number of rows affected by the Action query.
' You can display this to the user, store it in a table, or trigger an action
' if an unexpected number (e.g. 0 rows when you expect > 0).
lngRowsAffected = dbs.RecordsAffected

dbs.Execute "DELETE FROM tbl_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced WHERE Bad", dbFailOnError
lngRowsDeleted = dbs.RecordsAffected    
End Sub
```

SQL Code:

```sql
SELECT 
tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog, 
[MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]+[Total_Gross_kWh] AS Maui_Gross_kWh_Produced,
[Total_Aux]+[Total_Aux_kWh] AS Maui_Gross_Aux_kWh_Produced, [MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]-[Total_Aux]+[Total_Net_kWh] AS Maui_Net_kWh_Produced, 
Round(([Total_MBTU_Burned]*1000000)/([MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]+[Total_Gross_kWh]),0) AS Maui_Gross_BTU_kWh, 
Round([Total_MBTU_Burned]*1000000/([MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]-[Total_Aux]+[Total_Net_kWh]),0) AS Maui_Net_BTU_kWh, 
Round(([MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]+[Total_Gross_kWh])/[Total_Barrels_Burned],0) AS Maui_Gross_kWh_BBL, 
Round(([MPP_Daily_Gross_Gen_kWh]-[Total_Aux]+[Total_Net_kWh])/[Total_Barrels_Burned],0) AS Maui_Net_kWh_BBL 

INTO tbl_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced

FROM ((tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport 
INNER JOIN tbl_KPP_DailyGenerationReport 
ON tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog = tbl_KPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog) 
INNER JOIN tbl_MPP_Aux_DailyGenerationReport 
ON tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog = tbl_MPP_Aux_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog) 
INNER JOIN qry_Maui_Total_Fuel_Burned 
ON tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog = qry_Maui_Total_Fuel_Burned.DateLog
WHERE (((tbl_MPP_DailyGenerationReport.DateLog)=[Forms]![Power Supply Reports]![PS_Report_Date]));​
```

Comment: What does `qry_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced` do? Can you post its SQL? Are you sure that it works when you run it directly (without vba)?

Comment: I just verified that it works without vba.  It creates one row of data and puts it in a table which is then referenced for the report.  I put the sql code on the post.

Comment: Ok, I added Option Explicit and am getting stuck on the debug issues.  I had the delete the table object already in my db, but now I'm getting the following run-time error "3061: Too few parameters.  Expected 1" when I execute the code: dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError.  From looking at my local variables all the parameters looks to be in place.  Any ideas to why I'm still getting an error?

Comment: I think I'm getting a little closer.  I referenced the syntax for the query to have square brackets: sql="[qry_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced]".  But now my error is "3078: ..cannot find the input table or query..."  I've made sure that the query was named the same but is still not working. My saved query is a make table query.  Is there a different syntax for this?

Comment: @HansUp Yes, I can share it.  What's the best way to share it?  Github?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I intended it to update the end date and the user will have to enter an end date if they want to do a longer period report.  The reason you get that error is that table should be deleted before you run that query.  I haven't added any code to delete the table from VBA since I was just trying to get this code to execute without errors.

Comment: @HansUp I'm using the DoCmd.OpenQuery syntax and that's able to run the query for me.  I'm just trying to run the query using VBA so I can run it in the background without any warnings.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run your queries without warnings:

```
Private Sub PS_Report_Date_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tbl_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced WHERE Bad"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @neuralgroove
This worked for me, except now I get a "Enter Paramater Value for: Bad".  I'm assuming this is used for any errors in the data, do you know how I can get rid of this prompt?

Comment: I was gonna say something about that query, the WHERE clause is looking for a condition (like WHERE Field1='bad' or something) Without seeing your dataset i'm not sure what the condition is looking for

Comment: my understanding of that WHERE clause is if it has a bad data point or a "null" data point then you would delete it from the table.  I removed it from my VBA code in the meantime, but for the future is there a way I can look at null values and output N/A instead of deleting it from the table?

Comment: when querying the table you can use iif(ISNULL(value),"N/A",value) or you could run an update query to update those fields to N/A..`UPDATE tbl_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced SET FieldName="N/A" WHERE FieldName IS NULL` or `UPDATE tbl_Maui_Division_KWH_Produced SET FieldName="N/A" WHERE FieldName=""`